# Set the value of a button to equal the answer of an SQL query

Tags: php, javascript, sql, button, innerhtml

My code has a text input and submit button which on return hides that form and displays a new button, which works. The problem I'm having is setting the value of the button (or innerHTML) to the answer in my query (which will always only be one). I have the following code:

```
echo '<form><button id="HCP_Btn" name="HCP_Btn" style="display:none"></button></form>';

    $HCP_num = $_POST['HCP_num'];
    $HCP_Query="SELECT * FROM HomeCareProviders WHERE Number='". $HCP_num."'";


    $HCP_result= mysql_query($HCP_Query) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($HCP_result)==0){
        echo 'Sorry there are no Home Care Providers with the number entered.';
    }
    //HCP_Btn.innerHTML='.$row["name"].';
    else {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($HCP_result);
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                HCP_Btn.style.display="";
                document.form.HCP_Btn.innerHTML='.$row["name"].';       
              </script>';                           
    }
```

Comment: The problem is probably because Your button's id is **HCP_Btn** but in the JS further You are accessing it like **HCP_btn** - the problem could be small **b**.

Comment: @ shadyyx Thanks for that. It still didn't work, however!

Comment: Check my answer, I did an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Javascript code

`echo '<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("HCP_Btn").style.display="";
document.getElementById("HCP_Btn").innerHTML="'.$row["name"].'";

</script>';`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably because Your button's id is **HCP_Btn** but in the JS further You are accessing it like **HCP_btn** - the problem could be small **b**. Also You are missing quotes for the `innerHTML` value.

Change the line

```
document.form.HCP_btn.innerHTML='.$row["name"].';
```

to

```
document.form.HCP_Btn.innerHTML="'.$row["name"].'";
                  ^             ^                ^
    make the b uppercase    add quotes ----------^
```

---

**EDIT:** Have You ever tried jQuery? It is commonly and widely used JavaScript framework that makes JS programming so much easier (after You know it)... With jQuery, You could just do:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$("#HCP_Btn").css({"display":""}).html("'.$row['name'].'");
</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

For first change it like this

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                //HCP_Btn.style.display="";
                document.form.HCP_btn.innerHTML=\''.$row["name"].'\';       
              </script>';
```

for second check if $row["name"] gives you the right value and at last check you javascript console for errors.

Also HCP_Btn.style.display=""; mean nothing like this.

Comment: @ Alessandro Gabrielli The query gives the right result anyway. The added slashes didn't change anything

Comment: yes, and also comment the row before or change it document.getElementById('HCP_btn')

Comment: @ Alessandro Gabrielli The button is set to style=display:none to hide it. Then after another button is clicked I'm changing it to be visible with the line HCP_Btn.style.display="";

Comment: I can't see the whole code but if you echoed the form before of document.form.HCP_btn.innerHTML=\''.$row["name"].'\'; then it must works because it works for me

Comment: You refere to an object calling it just for name? or hcp_Btn is a variable?

Comment: @ Alessandro Gabrielli Ok changing to document.getElementById did the trick. Thanks

Comment: np, try to debug javascript with a good console, it will make your life easier. Waiting for updates

Comment: @user2363025 For last , set the form name (name="form") if you want to refer it by name. My tip is anyway to refer object by id, because it is unique

Answer (score 0):

How is the information from your JavaScript call returned to the innerHTML itself? When does it get called and changed? I think you should do that first.

You have an user pressing a button. Then you go to the database using PHP (need a new request response for that), with AJAX or JavaScript you could make it work client side.

I think that you are mixing up server side and client side issues. You should at least need a function call on the onClick event to toggle the display of the button and show the information. That onClick event should call a JavaScript function and that will handle the change.

Comment: @ Loek Bergman They were two different buttons. When one is displayed the other is hidden. I got it working. The only issue was not using document.getElementById :) It gets called when another (different button) was clicked

Comment: Good to hear you solved it. That is most important. Thanks for the clarification of the process. I did not read well enough. Is it correct that you do not needed to use JavaScript? What I see is static JavaScript without function call. PHP is in fact doing the job. Adding the JavaScript directly to the button using PHP might simplify your code. Always good for maintenance.